# Finding the derived group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need help to answer the folowing problem:

> Let $F$ be a field, $n\ge 1$ and $G=F^n\bigoplus F^n\bigoplus Mat(n,F).$ That is an element of $G$ has the form $(v,w,X)$ where $v$ and $w$ are n-by-1 vectors and $X$ is $n$-by$-n$ matrix, all with entires in $F$.
>
> Define an operator on $G$ by:
>
> $$(v_1,w_1,X_1)(v_2,w_2,X_2)=(v_1+v_2,w_1+w_2,X_1+X_2+v_1w_2^t)$$
>
> Show that $G'=\left\{(0,0,X), X\in Mat(n,F)\right\}$. Where $G'$ is the derived group of $G$ i.e $G′=\left\{[a,b],a,b∈G\right\}$

Comment: Have you tried looking at what $[a,b]$ looks like for generic $a,b\in G$?

Answer (score 0):

yes i proved one inclusion:I poved the following inclusion:

we need to compute the commutator $[(v_1, w_1, X_1), (v_2, w_2, X_2)]$. Before jumping into the computation it's clearer to first write out the inverses.

We have:

$(v_1, w_1, X_1)^{-1} 
    = (-v_1, -w_1, -X_1 + v_1 w_1^t)$

and

$(v_2, w_2, X_2)^{-1} 
    = (-v_2, -w_2, - X_2 + v_2 w_2^t)$

Then

$[(v_1, w_1, X_1), (v_2, w_2, X_2)]$

$= (v_1, w_1, X_1)(v_2, w_2, X_2) (v_1, w_1, X_1)^{-1} (v_2, w_2, X_2)^{-1}$

$= (v_1, w_1, X_1)(v_2, w_2, X_2)(-v_1, -w_1,  - X_1 + v_1 w_1^t) (-v_2, -w_2, - X_2 + v_2 w_2^t)$

The $v$'s and $w$'s all cancel out nicely in the first two coordinates. The third coordinate is some $n \times n$ matrix.

We have just proved that the set of commutators is a subset of the set of all elements of the form $(0, 0, X)$.

So we have shown that

$G'\subset \{(0,0,X)\}$.
Please help me to prove the other inclusion.
Thanks in advance.